# iterate through two std::lists simultaneously

Tags: c++, iterator, std

Sorry if this is too simple a question.

Prior error checking ensures `l1.size() == l2.size()`.

```
std::list<object1>::iterator it1 = l1.begin();
std::list<object2>::iterator it2 = l2.begin();

while(it1 != l1.end() && it2 != l2.end()){

  //run some code

  it1++;
  it2++;
}
```

Is this a reasonable approach, or is there a more elegant solution? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Minor point:  The common idiom for incrementing an iterator uses prefix rather than postfix ++.  I.e. ++it1; rather than it1++;   There is an obscure performance related reason for this.

Comment: And another minor point: if l1.size() == l2.size() you only need one test in the while condition.

Comment: @DaleWilson: It's not that obscure. It's simply the copy construction overhead incurred by complex (not in the mathematical sense) types needed for the post-increment operator.

Comment: @ Dale Wilson thanks for the tip. is that only for iterators or general variable increments?  The compiler won't optimize that?

Comment: @TomSwifty: It really depends on what you're incrementing. `operator++()` is supposed to return a `T&`, while `operator++(int)` returns a `T`. However, I'm not sure if it really poses problem with today's compilers, given return-value optimization, move semantics and all.

Comment: It's for iterators of given object type. The reason is that the post increment makes a copy, increments it and then returns the original.  It's the copy that is expensive.

Comment: @MikeSeymour yup i was wrong

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I prefer to use `for` if increments unconditionally occurs:

```
for(; it1 != l1.end() && it2 != l2.end(); ++it1, ++it2)
{
    //run some code
}
```

You can omit one test while the size of lists are the same, but I'm not sure what's going on in *run some code*!

Comment: Can you include init in for loop head as well? `for(iterator it1 = l1.begin(), iterator it2 = l2.begin() ...` ?

Comment: Yes it is possible

Answer (score 1):

I think this is perfectly reasonable (except that I'd use pre-increment rather than post-increment).

You could consider using a ["zip iterator"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=c%2B%2B+zip+iterator) of some sort, but it's not totally obvious that this would be worth the hassle in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing a simple operation on each pair of objects, you can use `std::transform`.

Answer (score 1):

It is reasonable to do it the way you have,  there are some other approaches you could take to minimise the amount of checks being done:

If you have already checked both lengths are equal (as stated as a prior check), a standard for loop may well suffice, which eliminates the access of two variables and relies only on the increment of one variable:

```
for (int i = 0; i< l1.size();i++)
{
    // run some code here
}
```

However you would need to use `advance()` or `next()` to march through the objects in the list within the "some code here".