# Error while simultaneously accessing members of two lists?

Tags: c++, list, visual-c++, stl, iterator

I am facing some unknown errors while iterating through two lists simultaneously in c++ (visual studio). Two lists are of the same length.

I am following the procedure, mentioned in ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933537/iterate-through-two-stdlists-simultaneously)). Unable to figure out where am I making mistake. Could anybody help me resolve this error

Function with for loop

```
int Two_Lists_ForLoop(std::initializer_list<dmat> list1, std::initializer_list<string> list2)
{
    std::list<dmat>::iterator it1 = list1.begin();
    std::list<string>::iterator it2 = list2.begin();

    for (; it1 != list1.end() && it2 != list2.end(); ++it1, ++it2){

        //run some code
        cout << *it1 << endl;
        cout << *it2 << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Function with while loop

```
int Two_Lists_WhileLoop(std::initializer_list<dvec> list1, std::initializer_list<string> list2)
{
    std::list<dvec>::iterator it1 = list1.begin();
    std::list<string>::iterator it2 = list2.begin();

    while (it1 != list1.end() && it2 != list2.end()) {

        //run some code
        cout << *it1 << endl;
        cout << *it2 << endl;

        it1++;
        it2++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've included list.h headerfile. The errors I am getting are as follows (I do not know, how to resolve these errors)

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Visual Studio have a tab where you can get the errors as text. Please copy-paste the text *as text*, in full and complete. And please mark out the lines in the code (with comments) where the errors are. Preferably create a [mcve] to show us, one that replicates the problem and which we ourselves can try out and see the errors first-hand.

Comment: As a hint though: `std::initialize_list` is not a `std::list`, the two types are incompatible, as are their iterators.

Comment: Instead of `std::list<dvec>::iterator` you should use `std::initializer_list<dvec>::iterator` (because the container is an `intializer_list`, not a `list`). Or simply use the `auto` keyword.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you very much, the problem is solved. I replaced `std::list` with `std::initialize_list`.

Comment: @KaenbyouRin Thank you very much, the problem is solved. Could you please provide the syntax for using `auto` keyword in `std::initialize_list`

Comment: @The_Learner  `auto it1 = list1.begin();` and `auto it2 = list2.begin();`